# Routes currently require literal id of model attribute, rather than what would make sense given the context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My app basically consists of a user taking a course, and going through various steps to complete the course.  However, I believe there is a problem with my routing.   Right now here is the route for course 1 > level 1 > step 1

```
 http://localhost:3000/courses/1/levels/1/steps/1
```

Here is the route for course 2 > level 1 (of course 2) > step 1 (of course 2):

```
 http://localhost:3000/courses/2/levels/4/steps/10
```

It requires the literal ID of the step and level.  In reality, I think it would make more sense if the above route said :

```
 http://localhost:3000/courses/2/levels/1/steps/1
```

or even

```
http://localhost:3000/course_title/levels/1/steps/1
```

How would I achieve this and does the routing make sense to do so?

Routes.rb

```
Serenity::Application.routes.draw do


  root to: 'static_pages#home' 


  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :users
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :courses
    end
  end
  resources :courses do
    resources :levels, only: [:show] do
      resources :steps, only: [:show]
    end
  end
  resources :assignments, only: [:create, :destroy]

end
```

Here are my models in a nutshell: a user takes courses through the assigment model, and each course has levels and steps.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :courses, through: :assignments

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :course_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, through: :assignments
  has_many :levels

class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course

class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :level
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is shallow nesting.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Look for section **2.7.2 Shallow Nesting**

Comment: I am not sure this is what I am looking for - I am not necessarily trying to shorten my route, although if possible would be nice.  Instead, for example, I am trying to have step with id of 12 actually be called step 1 when it is a new course and new level.

Comment: The restful way would be to append '/new' at the end and not '1'. But if you create your new level and new step whenever you create a new course, you'd get your id automatically. Make sure you're not confusing the `id` of your resources with its `order`. By that I mean, "give me the first level of this course" vs "give me the level with an id of 1".